# Why Kubernetes (Skaffold) deletes MongoDB Persistent data locally on each restart?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I am running all the files with `skaffold dev` command. Each time I kill it with CTRL + C it will delete everything from the cluster such as pods, services, etc. Once I reconnect, I am not seeing the data. What am I missing here? I want to have a database data somewhere on my hard drive, so once I boot the device, it loads the data?

Here is my code:

PersistenceVolumeClaim yaml file ( by default it should take piece of my hard-drive?)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: database-persistent-volume-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

Service yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-mongo
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

And lastly the Deployment yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-mongo
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: mongodb-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: database-persistent-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: auth-mongo
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongodb-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
```

Comment: if that is all of your resources I don't think this will work. A PersistentVolumeClaim needs to be bound to a PersistentVolume. There is no default, where the storage is located but needs to be defined in the PV. By using "hostPath" as type, it will take storage from machine running kubernetes

Comment: @meaningqo what should I do? Any reference on how to make it?

Comment: @AmelAmcëMuminovic You can check this open issue about PVC on GitHub: [PVC get deleted on clean up (when bound by a Deployment)](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/4366)